# Why do I have to manually approve comments from one of my users who already has an approved comment?

Tags: comments

I have the "Comment author must have a previously approved comment" option checked, and the "Comment must be manually approved" is very much unchecked. My blog is kinda unknown, and I only have 7 users and they are all family. ¯\(°_o)/¯ I only have two who comment regularly, and one of them is a moderator. His comments always get approved and are published immediately. But the other user's comment always have to be manually approved, even though I have the box that should make it so I only need to approve his comment once is checked. I don't get it... Is there some option that I don't know about that is inhibiting my user from commenting?